# create a .cur file on mac os x

Tags: cocoa

I'm looking for a way to create a .cur file on Mac OS X
I saw that there is a support for .cur file in the NSImage documentation but as far as I tested it I could not produce this file format.
Anny ideas ?
10x

Comment: //produce an NSImageRep class that supports cur format
Class curClass = [NSImageRep imageRepClassForFileType: @"CUR"];
//Register the object to the NSBitmapRep class
[NSBitmapImageRep registerImageRepClass:curClass];
//get the array of registered representations
regClasses = [NSBitmapImageRep registeredImageRepClasses];
//get the cur representation from the array
NSBitmapImageRep * curRep = [regClasses objectAtIndex:0];
//init the representation with the NSImage from the cursor (using NSCursor)

Answer (score 0):

http://www.graphic-converter.net/mac-graphic-converter.htm

Works on macs and converts images into .cur files.